# How can I install ubuntu server in a chroot environment?

Tags: ubuntu, chroot

I am using Ubuntu Karmic desktop. I want to install Ubuntu 8.04 LTS server in a chroot environment. Can anyone provide instructions on how to do this?. A Google search does not bring up anything useful (perhaps I am searching using the wrong keywords)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well
ypu have two choices : 
-install a Virtual machine on your computer (VirtualBox allows you to do that), you create a VM for your ubuntu and rulez :)
http://www.virtualbox.org/
Thus means you have a closed environment into which you could work freely.

-install a bare-metal hypervisor (Proxmox, VMWare ESXI) a on a server and create as many VM's as you want.

But it looks like you are more looking for the first solution

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean: you want to install a whole ubuntu distro inside a chroot jail?

Sounds more like you want to do a virtualized server instance on an existing server...

Comment: @Stanicpuppy: +1 for answering. Yes, its a virtualized server instance I want, so I can test my packages on the server before deploying the packages onto my remotely hosted server. What is the correct terminology for what I am trying to do. I have not been able to get any help anywhere and Google is not finding anything either (leading me to suspect that the terms I am searching on are incorrect)

Comment: To clarify, yes, it is a whole Ubuntu 8.04 LTS server distro I want to install in a "chroot jail" (if thats the correct terminology). the whole idea is so that I can test out my packages before deploying them to my remotely hosted server which is running Ubuntu 8.04 server LTS